# How to find physical interfaces on linux (without bridges, aliases, vlans ..)

Tags: linux, bash, networking

i need to identify physical interfaces on (Debian) Linux
if show into /sys/class/net i see all interfaces including bridges and vlans.

or it is possible with bash to check if one interface exists and if its physical or virtual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

extended solution, works on pi and other devices linke tinker board/rock64

```
systemctl -a | grep sys-devices-platform | grep '\-net-' | awk '{n=split($1,A,"-"); print A[n]}' | cut -d"." -f1
```

Answer (score 4):

Check for the `DEVTYPE` parameter in the `uevent` file residing in `/sys/class/net/<interface>/uevent`.

In my bridge interface:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/br0/uevent 
DEVTYPE=bridge
INTERFACE=br0
IFINDEX=3
```

While the real physical interface over which the bridge is created does not have the parameter:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/eth0/uevent
INTERFACE=eth0
IFINDEX=2
```

Comment: thank you for idea ;) physical interfaces have a "device" symlink in /sys/class/net/<interface>/ folder. Virtual devices not

Answer (score 2):

One way is to match symbolic link paths in `/sys/class/net/`:

```
$ ls -la /sys/class/net/

lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 18. 5. 04:51 docker0 -> ../../devices/virtual/net/docker0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 18. 5. 04:51 eno1 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0/net/eno1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 18. 5. 04:51 enp9s0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:09:00.0/net/enp9s0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 18. 5. 04:51 lo -> ../../devices/virtual/net/lo
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 18. 5. 19:17 macvtap0 -> ../../devices/virtual/net/macvtap0
```

`/devices/virtual/net/` path is present for all virtual interfaces.

So you can use `find` to match all links that are **not** containing `*/devices/virtual/net/*`:

```
$ find /sys/class/net/ -type l ! -lname '*/devices/virtual/net/*'
/sys/class/net/eno1
/sys/class/net/enp9s0
```

This can be turned to script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for iface in $(find /sys/class/net/ -type l ! -lname '*/devices/virtual/net/*' -printf '%f '); 
do
  echo "$iface is not virtual"
done
```

Example output:

```
# ./ifs.sh 
eno1 is not virtual
enp9s0 is not virtual
```

Answer (score 0):

two possible solution

1. show for `device` Symlink in `/sys/class/net/< interface >/` folder, it only appears on physical interfaces
2. ip -d show link you can find the different types of the interface

   ```
   if  [[ ! `ip -d link show ${int_name}  2>/dev/null >/dev/null` ]]; then
       echo "Interface ${int_name} does not exists"
   elif [[ `ip -d link show ${int_name} | tail -n +2 | grep loopback` ]] ; then
       echo is_local
   elif [[ `ip -d link show ${int_name} | tail -n +2 | grep vlan` ]] ; then
       echo is_vlan
   elif [[ `ip -d link show ${int_name} | tail -n +2 | grep bridge` ]] ; then
       echo is_bridge
   else
       echo is_physic
   fi
   ```

Answer (score 0):

better solution with systemd (example on raspberry pi with vlans/bridges)

```
systemctl -a | grep net-devices | grep -v "/sys/subsystem"
```